# What does coming-out mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

[image]In a movie I watched there was a scene where there was a couch delivered to a house. The owner of the house is telling some workers where to place it. She says "We were thinking in here" while pointing to a room which they were entering and after they are inside she points to a wall and says "with the **coming-out part** along the wall". The couch is basically a corner settee but two-piece not one, with a little table in-between. What is the coming-out part of a couch?

Comment: Are you able to post a screenshot of the movie showing the couch in question, or an image of a similar couch? In general I would say the "coming-out part" is any part of an otherwise smooth or uninterrupted object that juts out, often at a right angle, from the main body of the object.

Comment: What @randomhead said, and to make explicit that in this context the "coming-out-part" would mean the shorter section of a corner couch.

Comment: I added the screenshot :) The coming-out part is further along that wall with drapes.

Answer (score 1):

It means “the part that comes out”. The descriptive clause (“that comes out”) has been transformed into an adjective phrase (“coming-out”). Some similar constructions are:

> The **rubbed-out** part said something interesting. (There is a part of the writing *that was rubbed out*.)
>
> The **combed-over** part doesn’t hide much. (There is a part of their hair *that is combed over* the top of their head.)
>
> The **tidied-up** part looks as good as new. (There is a part of the area *that has been tidied up*.)

---

Exactly *what* part of the couch this is must depend on context. It likely means one side of the corner piece—the speaker considers one side (the longer one?) to be the “main” one, and in their mind, the other side “comes out” from there. They want that other side to lie along the wall.

It could equally mean other things for different furniture. A sofa bed has a part that “comes out” in the sense of folding out when needed. I personally might use “comes out” to describe the part of a corner piece that does *not* follow the wall (it “comes out” towards the middle of the room), but that’s clearly not the case here!

Answer (score 0):

Thé ‘coming out part’ would more than likely be the part that unfolds into a bed.